# How do i print multiple values separately in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm retrieving data from the database using an unique id. Now the problem is, all the values are being retrieved and are being printed in a single line. I want them below one another. I tried "
" "\n
" and also nl2br. If anyone could help me. Thanks in advance.

PHP file:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
die("connection couldn't be established");
}
if(isset($_POST['EnrNo']) === true && empty($_POST['EnrNo']) === false) {
//$Enr = $_POST['EnrNo'];
$EnrNo = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['EnrNo']);
$query = "Select * FROM cert WHERE EnrNo = '$EnrNo'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
  {
  echo ("EnrNo: " .$row["EnrNo"]);
  echo ("Name: " .$row["Name"]);
  echo ("Batch Code: " .$row["Batch Code"]); 
  echo ("Start Date: " .$row["Start Date"]);
  echo ("End Date: ".$row["End Date"]);
  echo ("Course: " .$row["Course"]);
  echo ("Duration: " .$row["Duration"]);
 }  mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo ('Data not found');
    };
?>
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Enr No: <input type="text" name="EnrNo" id="EnrNo" /><br/><br />
<input type="submit" name="retrieve" value="retrieve" id="EnrNo-sub" />
<div id="EnrNo-data"></div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('input#EnrNo-sub').on('click', function() { 
var EnrNo = $('input#EnrNo').val();
if (EnrNo != '') {
$.post('retrieve.php', {EnrNo: EnrNo}, function(data) { 
    $('div#EnrNo-data').text(data);

});

}


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "
", instead of "\n",
Example:

```
 echo "Value1  :".$value1."<br>";
 echo "Value2  :".$value2."<br>";
 echo "Value3  :".$value3."<br>";
 echo "Value4  :".$value4."<br>";
 echo "Value5  :".$value5."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you simply try:

```
echo ("Duration: " .$row["Duration"]."<br>");
```

`\n` is only visible in the source code, while `<br>` affects the html.

Comment: Still it is being printed in the same line. Any other option?

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. `<br>` forces a new line to begin, there is no way a browser can ignore that. Could you post exactly what you wrote now?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<br>` for line breaks and `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Otherwise the html will be escaped anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

**Html uses `BR` tag to insert a single line break.**

To have a value printed on a new line, you can add your line break tag `<BR />` after every line like this:

```
echo ("EnrNo: " .$row["EnrNo"]).'<BR />';
```

**Please Note :**

> In HTML, the `<br>` tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML, the `<br>` tag must be properly closed, like this: `<br />`

Comment: This is what being printed "
EnrNo: 11664<BR />Name: Mr. Ahmed MorsiBatch Code: 001-CCP-W-30-Jan- 2015<BR />Start Date: 30 Jan 2015<BR />End Date: 10 Apr 2015<BR />Course: Cost Engineering<BR />Duration: 40<BR />"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
  while ($row=$result->fetch_array())
  {
  echo ("EnrNo: " .$row["EnrNo"]."<br>");
  echo ("Name: " .$row["Name"]."<br>");
  echo ("Batch Code: " .$row["Batch Code"]."<br>"); 
  echo ("Start Date: " .$row["Start Date"]."<br>");
  echo ("End Date: ".$row["End Date"]."<br>");
  echo ("Course: " .$row["Course"]."<br>");
  echo ("Duration: " .$row["Duration"]."<br>");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($result->result() as $row)
```

{
  echo ("EnrNo: " .$row->EnrNo."
");
  echo ("Name: " .$row->Name."
");
  echo ("Batch Code: " .$row->Batch Code."
"); 
  echo ("Start Date: " .$row->Start Date."
");
  echo ("End Date: ".$row->End Date."
");
  echo ("Course: " .$row->Course."
");
  echo ("Duration: " .$row->Duration."
");
 }

Answer (score 0):

Considering your output, you could write a loop for the fields you wish to print and just append `<br>` to each line; also make sure you properly escape your output for HTML:

```
foreach (['EnrNo', 'Name', 'Batch Code', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Course', 'Duration'] as $field) {
    echo $field, ': ', htmlspecialchars($row[$field], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '<br>';
}
```